# Set certain fontsize for a certain part of my document

Tags: floats, miktex, fontsize, texniccenter, texify

I'm embedding a figure into my document which contains several `\put{}`-commands to place texts and formulas over the PDF-figure. The code looks of `BLA.pdf_tex` looks like this:

```
%% Creator: Inkscape 0.48.3.1, www.inkscape.org
%% PDF/EPS/PS + LaTeX output extension by Johan Engelen, 2010
%% Accompanies image file 'BLA.pdf' (pdf, eps, ps)
%%
%% To include the image in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics{.pdf}
%% To scale the image, write
%%   \def\svgwidth{}
%%   \input{.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics[width=]{.pdf}
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{547.7bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,1.61511777)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{BLA.pdf}}%
    \put(0.25579697,0.87675735){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[b]{\smash{EIN TEXT HIER}}}%
    \put(0.25579697,0.8563082){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[b]{\smash{eine formel hier: $g_{lim} > Gmin$}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

Embedded via:

```
\begin{figure}[thb]
\centering
\hfill
\subfloat[htb][BLA]{\fcolorbox{plotBord}{plotPadd}{
\def\svgwidth{0.95\textwidth}
  \input{BLA.pdf_tex}
}\label{fig:blaaaaaaa}}
\hfill\null\\
\caption{ASD}\label{fig:ASD} 
\end{figure}
```

I tried myself by using a `group` like this:

```
\begingroup
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont
\begin{figure}[thb]
\centering
\hfill
\subfloat[htb][BLA]{\fcolorbox{plotBord}{plotPadd}{
\def\svgwidth{0.95\textwidth}
  \input{BLA.pdf_tex}
}\label{fig:blaaaaaaa}}
\hfill\null\\
\caption{ASD}\label{fig:ASD} 
\end{figure}
\endgroup
```

But it doesn't work. I don't want to put a `\footnotesize` into each `\put`-command - and then maybe later I've got to change it back again to another fontsize for some reason.

Is there a simple solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: just use 
`\begin{figure}[thb]\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont` (or `\begin{figure}[thb]\small` if small is 10pt in your class.)

Comment: also you need `%` here `{plotPadd}{%` and here `\def\svgwidth{0.95\textwidth}%` and here `\input{BLA.pdf_tex}%` or you will have spurious white space in the fcolorbox

Comment: Wow it really works, thanks. So I assume the figure-environment has it's own let's say `local` variable and thus setting the fontsize BEFORE the figure doesn't affect the scope inside? Can you maybe tell me why I'm having problems with unicode characters (German Umlaute) in the put-commands? I don't have any problems within the whole document except in the embedding of the pdf_tex-File

Comment: yes  it does `\def \@floatboxreset {%
        \reset@font
        \normalsize
        \@setminipage`

Comment: Probably the pdf_tex file is not in the same encoding as your main file. Use an editor and save them both as utf8 or both as iso-8859-1 and then declare either utf8 or latin1 to latex

Comment: Yeah I converted the file to "ANSI" in notepad++ and it works like a charm. Encodings can really cause some headache sometimes. One last thing about your comment using the `%` and the end of a like. I've already encountered this issue that there's a space in front of a new paragraph when I put some code to insert a table in between and use `\end{tabular}` instead of `\end{tabular}%`. The problem is: When I use `\end{tabular}%` I CAN'T USE the comment-package anymore to strip out all tables/figures/code-blocks (to see how much text I really wrote). Any advice?

Comment: Using this: `\usepackage{comment} \excludecomment{figure} \let\endfigure\relax  \excludecomment{lstlisting} \let\endlstlisting\relax \excludecomment{equation} \let\endequation\relax \excludecomment{table} \let\endtable\relax \let\beq\iffalse \let\eeq\fi` to strip out every non-text element from the final document. It doesn't work when there's a `%` behind a `end`-tag :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12733/discussion-between-bjoern-and-david-carlisle)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use

```
\begin{figure}[thb]\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont
```

or

```
\begin{figure}[thb]\small
```

if small is 10pt in your class.

Also you need `%` here `{plotPadd}{%` and here `\def\svgwidth{0.95\textwidth}%` and here `\input{BLA.pdf_tex}%` or you will have spurious white space in the fcolorbox

Comment: Thanks, maybe you could quickly help me with your suggestion using the `%` :-)